# How limit scan results in DynamoDB .NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

i have a question. I want to limit the result of scan over dynamodb. I read in documentation that "Limit" parameter on ScanRequest do this works, but this code it seems not working.

I have 14 records, and this scan returns exactly 14 records, but should return 10. What i am doing wrong?

```
public IList<Contact> GetContacs(string firstContactToScan)
        {
            using (var context = new DynamoDBContext(new AmazonDynamoDBClient()))
            {
                var data = context.FromScan<Contact>(new ScanOperationConfig {Limit = 10}).ToList();
                return data;
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();

var request = new ScanRequest
{
    TableName = "yourTableName",
    Limit = 10
};

var response = client.Scan(request);
var result = response.ScanResult;

foreach (Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> item in response.ScanResult.Items)
{
  PrintItem(item);
}
```

There are other options also which you can specify in the request following is the 
[Reference Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetScanning.html).

Hope that helps

Comment: I would like to do this using the high level client DynamoDbContext. It is not obvious if this is possible.